# Firebase data structure for Profiles

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to mentally work out how to construct my app's database structure based on it's function.

When a user registers an account to my Firebase backend they will be prompted to input information of their "Profile 1". Name, age, contact info and an image will be loaded into this profile.

They can then choose to create an additional profile consisting of exactly the same data: Name, age etc. They can continue to create further profiles.

So what I'm trying to figure out is now how to arrange my database to support this sort of structure. One user, multiple "set's" of data / Profiles. 
So when they open the app later on when they have multiple profiles created , they will be able to choose which one to load. Hence needing some sort of mechanism telling the database to load that specific set/profile of data.

Hope I made some sense out of this. Harder to explain than I thought.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One question; when you say additional profile containing exactly the same data, what would be the function of that duplicated data? If it's exactly the same then you would really need to only store it once. Perhaps you mean that it duplicates the data which can then be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
users
  uid_0
    defaultProfile: "-YN9998ijssios"
    profiles
      -Yhnaiosioajsd
          profileName: "profile 1"
          name: "Bill"
          age: "102"
          contactInfo: "bill@dudes.com"
      -YN9998ijssios
          profileName: "profile 2"
          name: "Bill"
          age: "102"
          contactInfo: "bill@dudes.com"
      -YP989jsmskooo
          profileName: "profile 3"
          name: "Bill"
          age: "102"
          contactInfo: "bill@dudes.com"
```

You could also separate the profiles into a separate node, which would flatten the data (a good thing) but it may not be necessary since it's a one to many relationship, user to their profiles.

When you observe the user node to load it, take the value stored in the defaultProfile child node and select it from the snapshot (dictionary) that was loaded in. That code is just a basic observing (reading) of a node.

My answer to

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038689/swift-firebase-fetch-users-data-only-if-it-matches-current-users-data/41046405#41046405)

is almost the exact same code pattern (Swift) if you need some examples.

Comment: This looks very logical indeed. But "uid_0" I guess is the User's ID. And I can see that "profiles" will be the child that holds the upcoming profile-childreen. But what is "defaultProfile...xx" suppose to be/function as?

Comment: @Benni The defaultProfile child would be well, which one of the profiles is the default one. If the user has 10 profiles then one of them would be the 'main' profile he would be using. If the user decides to use a different profile as their main one, then store that key as the value of defaultProfile. It wasn't included in your question but I added it in case you wanted to use something along those lines. And yes, uid would be the users id, which his a typical design pattern in Firebase.